# How are the apps on iPhone organized when deleted?

Tags: iphone

I am looking to find out how the apps are organized when you look under the App Store go to purchased and not this phone. Are they organized from
Recently deleted or is there another random
way that is done?

Comment: Looking at the list of apps "Not on this iPhone" on my own iPhone, it looks like reverse chronological order - latest apps at the top of the list; earliest apps at the bottom. I have no authoritative source for a precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

The list is organised on first download date. The earliest downloaded apps are on the bottom of the list. The most recently downloaded apps are on the top of the list.